# wpf how to edit datagrid row

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview

I'm using datagrid as the temporary list that until I decide to insert in the database all the data remain in datagrid. I'm adding functions like adding new records, deleting or editing. but I can not change selectedrow 
my code is

```
gridlist.Items.Add(new { num_ins = num_ins.Text, dat_ins = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()} --> and many other value
```

and for delete

```
  var selectedItem = gridlist.SelectedItem;
        if (selectedItem != null)
        {
            gridlist.Items.Remove(selectedItem);
        }
```

i want to make something like this

```
gridlist.Columns[0].gridlist.Items[1]= "my value";
```

I wanted to know if it is possible to do this directly from the datagrid as a removal or creation of new records

Comment: Please translate the first portion of your post - SO is for english..

Comment: I'm sorry I rewrote it in English

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities.

1. If you always just add an anonymous type to the Items collection, then it is not possible no update the individual column values. You can however, update the entire row

   gridlist.Items[0] = new { num_ins = 1, dat_ins = DateTime.Now};
2. If you could create a class/structure with public properties for the items being added, then you can update the individual properties of the items.

   public class temp
   {
   public int num_ins {get;set;}
   public DateTime dat_ins {get;set;}
   }

   ((gridlist.Items[0] as temp)).num_ins = 3;